# set variable result in case statement to be used again in the same select statement

Tags: case

Is it possible to create, inside a single select statement, like this:

```
SELECT  
   name,  
   CASE  
      WHEN name = 'a' THEN 'a'  
      ELSE 'b'  
   END tag,  
   CASE  
      WHEN tag = 'a' THEN 'a2'  
      ELSE tag = 'b2'  
   END tag2  
FROM table_name
```

My reason is there is a previous column on the single statement where I want to use its case statement result on my other column.

I want to know if it can be done using variables like:

```
SELECT  
   name,  
   CASE  
      WHEN name = 'a' THEN 'a'  
      ELSE 'b'
   END @result = tag,  
   CASE  @result
      WHEN 'a' THEN 'a2'  
      ELSE 'b2'  
   END tag2  
FROM table_name
```

I know the second code is incorrect but that is the logic I need. Thanks guys!

Comment: Is this for SQL Server, some other DBMS or a general SQL question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to either repeat the expression, or derive it in a separate scope, e.g.:

```
SELECT name, tag, CASE
   WHEN tag = 'a' THEN 'a2' 
   ELSE 'b2' END AS tag2
FROM
(
   SELECT  name, CASE  
        WHEN name = 'a' THEN 'a'  
        ELSE 'b' END AS tag
   FROM dbo.table_name
) AS derived;
```

Comment: can you change the `alias =` to `AS alias`? The question is tagged with sql only,

Comment: @ypercube Was an educated guess based on all of OP's other questions.

Comment: OK then, I asked the OP on a comment. By the way, MySQL has also variables named `@name` and maybe other DBMS as well, I don''t know

Comment: thanks Aaron! I found it useful. BTW, it's for SQL Server. But I think its logically applicable to MyQSL and/or Oracle

Comment: @edgar imho general or multi-platform SQL questions are rarely useful because so few non-trivial problems can have one single universal answer.